# Google App Engine Project Deploys but Doesn't Update at xxx.appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine

I've created a Google app locally and am trying to see it on *app_id*.appspot.com. The project for the app is set up on Google Developer's console and I can successfully deploy from the App Engine Launcher with the following log output:

```
    2015-07-17 08:42:59 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-    u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--   oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\xxxx/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update',    'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\app-id\default']"
    08:43 AM Application: app-id; version: 6
    08:43 AM Host: appengine.google.com
    08:43 AM 
    Starting update of app: app-id, version: 6
    08:43 AM Getting current resource limits.
    08:43 AM Scanning files on local disk.
    08:43 AM Scanned 500 files.
    08:43 AM Cloning 2 static files.
    08:43 AM Cloning 727 application files.
    08:43 AM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
    08:43 AM Uploaded 1 files and blobs.
    08:43 AM Compilation starting.
    08:43 AM Compilation completed.
    08:43 AM Starting deployment.
    08:43 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
    08:43 AM Deployment successful.
    08:43 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
    08:43 AM Completed update of app: app-id, version: 6
    08:43 AM Uploading index definitions.
    2015-07-17 08:43:22 (Process exited with code 0)

    You can close this window now.
```

I'm on Windows 7 and have tried this on cmd as well with the same output. I've tried changing the version number, waiting overnight, and setting "default_expiration" to "1m" in app.yaml, but no dice. The address *app_id*.appspot.com still shows a very old version of the app. Any suggestions about what to do from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are uploading your application with version label 6. Log into the Google Cloud Console and check to see if version 6 is set as the default serving version.

`https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-app-id>/appengine/versions`

Comment: Spot on. Wasn't even aware of that feature!

Comment: It also lets you run parallel versions of your code, addressable by http://<version>.<app_id>.appspot.com or https://<version>-dot-<app_id>.appspot.com which is nice for verification on deployment.

Comment: if you click on the link to the app version in that page, you also get the error message that's causing the deploy to fail :)